# entity to SQl,linq to sql query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

Find all the different persons that appear in the table charged with the responsible entity that creates a connection more or more persons and entities projects?

how to convert sql query in there technologies?
Sql query is

```
select distinct p.PersonID,p.FirstName,p.LastName
from Responsible tr inner join People p on p.PersonID=tr.People_PersonID;
```

My attemot is

```
        string query = @"SELECT value empl 
                        FROM TicketBaseEntities.Responsible AS tr 
                        INNER JOIN TicketBaseEntities.People AS empl 
                        on empl.PersonID =tr.Responsibles.People_PersonID where tr.Responsibles !=null";
        return Context.CreateQuery<Employee>(query).Distinct();
```

Error message is:

'People_PersonID' is not a member of 'Transient.collection[TicketBaseModel.Person(Nullable=True,DefaultValue=)]'. To extract a property of a collection element, use a subquery to iterate over the collection. Near simple identifier, line 5, column 63.

Comment: Have you tried it yourself?  Can you show your progress?

Comment: My tried is sql query ....and I beginner in entity or linq

Comment: Why do you use entity sql and not linq?

Comment: all the same entity or linq SQL :D

Answer (score 0):

```
(from tr in Responsible
join from p in People on tr.People_PersonID equals p.PersonID
select p.PersonID,p.FirstName,p.LastName).Distinct()
```

You can Implement IComparer interface to use Distinct() function for Class People

Comment: On this model is Implement  IEnumeble interface

Comment: sorry it was IEqualityComparer<People>,you can find more help at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx